# With the python debugger, is there a way to create a set of breakpoints before calling `pdb.runcall()`?

Tags: python, pdb

With the python debugger, is there a way to create a set of breakpoints before calling `pdb.runcall()`?

I took a look through the documentation and didn't see any way to create additional breakpoints or provide a .pdbrc config directly to the instance.

I have this:

```
def debug_jobs_from_lists(username, json_string, skip=None):
    import pdb
    import rlcompleter
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.test.client import RequestFactory
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from batsapi.multi import multi

    if skip is None:
        skip = []

    rf = RequestFactory()
    request = rf.post(
        reverse('jobs-api'),
        data=json_string,
        content_type='application/json')

    request.user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    pdb_instance = pdb.Pdb(skip=['django.*'] + skip)
    pdb_instance.complete = rlcompleter.Completer(locals()).complete

    # Add breakpoint here to break in an underlying function

    pdb_instance.runcall(multi, request)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try out:

```
pdb.set_trace()
```